# How to submit single form element with submit button?

Tags: html, input

I have form in which there is two submit button with one button i have to post one form element value or with another submit i have to submit another form elements values.

Comment: Why dont you just make two forms?

Comment: Why don't you submit both with one button and check for `null` values ?

Comment: Any submit button within a form will submit the form. Submit buttons outside the form would do nothing by themselves unless JavaScript is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using JavaScript to go on a mass disabling exercise, you can't.

Only the clicked submit button will be a successful control (and thus appear in the submitted data … make sure it has a name and a value). Use that to determine (on the server) which button was clicked.

Then ignore all the inputs not associated with that submit button.

---

That said, your question implies that none of the inputs are associated with both buttons; so you would probably be better off separating them into two separate forms.